# Request handling in Zend Framework 2 compared with request handling in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, zend-framework2

In the Zend Framework 1 Bibel "Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development" by Keith Pope the ZF1 request handling is described as follows:

> The process can be broken down like this:
>
> 1. A request is made and the Request Object is created.
> 2. The routeStartup event is fired.
> 3. The Router processes the request.
> 4. The routeShutdown event is fired.
> 5. The dispatchLoopStartup event is fired.
> 6. The dispatch loop is started.
> 7. The preDispatch event is fired.
> 8. The Dispatcher calls the Action Controller.
> 9. The Action Controller writes to the Response Object.
> 10. The postDispatch event is fired.
> 11. If there are actions left to call, then go to Step 7.
> 12. The dispatchLoopShutdown event is fired.
> 13. The Response is sent back.

[image]

Does this still apply to the request handling in Zend Framework 2? If not: What is new? How does look the new schema?

Comment: It applies at face value , but internally some of the things are changed , I believe there are several new entities  that are added into the ecosystem . such as service manager , event manager , and event listeners , service locator , etc ... I think its very difficult to represent it in the form of a diagram . Here is the class map diagram http://bit.ly/ZeeEQa and there is one more rough diagram by  Enrico Zimuel  in his presentation here http://slidesha.re/Jl0kQq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flowchart of the request in ZF2 is different than in ZF1, because ZF2 MVC is an event-driven architecture. See the flowchart here:

http://zendframework2.de/en/cheat-sheet.html

I think it is available in multiple languages.

Hope this helps :)